# Tables with infinite scroll pagination

Tags: flutter

**I'm dealing with a challenge of creating a table with multiple data obtained from a paginated API. This page should have infinite scroll pagination where the user, upon reaching the end of the table, loads more data related to the next page**

I tried using the [data_table_2](https://pub.dev/packages/data_table_2) package, which includes the "PaginatedDataTable2" widget that has similar functionality to the native Flutter "PaginatedDataTable" but with some improvements and added conveniences. I thought of using the component's controller to detect when the user reaches the end of the table and emit an event to fetch more data from the API (considering that I work with the BLoC pattern). However, the problem arises when the controller for PaginatedDataTable2 needs to be of type "PaginatorController" instead of the "ScrollController" that I expected. I couldn't figure out a way to determine when the user reaches the end of the table with this type of controller.

I opted for the native Flutter version where the controller is indeed of type "ScrollController." However, I didn't know how to make the default paginator of the "PaginatedDataTable" widget disappear so that I could work solely with an infinite scroll paginator. I also became quite stressed and struggled to define a scroll for the widget. These details are easily resolved with the data_table_2 package, which already includes a native scroll and an option to hide the native paginator of the widget.

My question is:
Has anyone had any experience creating tables with infinite scroll pagination? How did you do it, and what approach do you recommend?

I believe I can easily solve the logic part of this problem, but the limitations of the widgets are giving me some trouble, and I really need help. Thank you in advance for your attention!